# Command that indents lines of a C source file

Tags: text-processing, c, source, indentation

I need a way to auto-indent blocks on a C source file within the
terminal. According to the norms.

Before:

```
int main() {
puts("Hello world");
}
```

After:

```
int main()
{
puts("Hello world");
}
```

Comment: I hope your “after” is missing some spaces before `puts`, otherwise I don't want to ever work with your code.

Comment: Are you saying that you want non-indented C source to appear indented when you view it in the terminal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The classic Unix tool for this job is `indent` (e.g., [GNU
indent](https://www.gnu.org/software/indent/)). Called in K&R mode, it
will indent your example code as you asked (assuming you actually want
`puts` indented):

```
$ indent -kr <sample.c
int main()
{
    puts("Hello world");
}
```

A more modern solution may be `clang-format`
(http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormat.html), which can be configured
in many ways according to a style file.

Comment: indent also has many, many formatting options. See the man page.